# Error: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, I need a help... it's my code:

```
<h2 class="title" id="ti"><span class="subtitle" id="sub"></span></h2>

document.getElementById('ti').innerHTML = "hello";
document.getElementById('sub').innerHTML = "my word";
```

on id: `ti` works fine but on id: `sub` return to me an error like this:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"
```

I'll appreciate some help ;)

PS: if I test without document.getElementById('ti').innerHTML = "hello", the document.getElementById('sub').innerHTML = "my word" works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Quentin told you, you are trying to access a id "sub" that does not exist.

The soluction for your problem, can be that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 class="title" id="ti">
        </h2>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var parent = document.getElementById('ti');
            var new = document.createElement("span");
            new.className = "subtitle";

            parent.innerHTML = "Hello";

            new.innerHTML = "My Word";
            parent.appendChild(new);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @PSantos ... that's what am talking about... ;)

Answer (score 6):

You replaced the span with the id `sub` with the text `hello`. That span no longer exists, so when you try to get it, you get `null` instead.

Comment: Right but if I test without document.getElementById('ti').innerHTML = "hello", the document.getElementById('sub').innerHTML = "my word" works fine....

Comment: @user2647038 — Why "Right *but*"? I said your problem is that you are replacing the span with the word "hello", *obviously* if you don't do that then you don't have a problem any more.

Comment: you're right ... but i want a solution code, not a solution "theoric"

Comment: @user2647038 — The solution to avoiding that error is to remove the line of code you have removed. If you want to achieve something in particular, then you have to say what you want to achieve instead of expecting people to guess what you are trying to do from your broken code.

Comment: Okay boss @Quentin ;)